# How to disable mouse wheel event in another application(WM_MOUSEWHEEL) using Handler

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, window-messages

I am able to close another application window (calculator) from my application by using the following code:

```
hwnd = FindWindow(null, "Calculator");SendMessage(hwnd,WM_CLOSE,0,IntPtr.Zero);
```

But I want to disable the mouse wheel in the same calculator application window. I tried the following way, but it doesn't work:

```
SendMessage(hwnd, WM_MOUSEWHEEL, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to Hook Into the Event and catch the occurence if you want to disable it for specific hWnds.

Look into this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373640(v=vs.85).aspx

If you define your callback function, it does need to take care about the correct distribution of the events to all Windows except the one you are searching for, despite that I'm not sure if this is just a clone of the Eventmessage or if they are only directed to your application if the hook is set.

Important is also that the code provided in the example is not complete,
it is missing a message-loop which actually does the grabbing from the message-queue.

Edit

the link mentioned below

http://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/create-simple-hidden-console-keylogger-c-sharp-0132757/

Comment: As i'm new to c#, can you post any example code to achieve the above functionality.

Comment: Hello ChanduRaj, no I can't. Don't have the time to get into this topic and I dont know if my skills are great enough to provide a good solution. WinEvents is btw. not the way to go, there's a similar named function SetWindowsHookEx which comes closer to what you want. Problematic is that it isn't really good documented, and the question still remains if the original thread still proccesses the message or not. It is indeed a hard thing to work on, even to grasp especially for beginners. But your roadmap should be: capture all WM_MOUSEWHEEL messages and decide afterwards what to do with them

Comment: I added a link in the answer which may be helpful to you. A Keylogger relies on similar functionality, maybe you can figure out how to go further.

Comment: SetWindowsHookEx need to set to parameters capturing mouse-messages respectively instead of keyboard-msgs